# How Do I make it where an admin can visit the same page as a manger?

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to make it where an "ADMIN" user type is able to access a "Manager" user type page. But an Admin isn't able to access the page, unless its user type is Manager. Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Here is my Code:

```
<?php 
    include('../blue/functions.php');

    if (!isManager()) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: ../login.php');
    }
 ?>

 <h1> Welcome Manager! </h1>
```

I also tried it like this but nothing still worked.

```
if (!isManager ()) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: ../login.php');
}

if (!isAdmin()) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: ../login.php');
}
```

Here is my Function Code:

```
function isAdmin() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin' ) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}

function isManager() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'Manager') {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if( isAdmin() || isManager() ) { // login html } else { // you must login first }`

Comment: I'd recomment to have increasing integer codes for access-types. like admin=10, manager=7, normal user=1,... - Then you can do a simple `accountLevel>=7`

Comment: @Jeff Definitely will do!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!isManager() || !isAdmin()) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: ../login.php');
}
```

Or better:

```
if (isManager() || isAdmin()) {
?>
    <h1> Welcome Manager! </h1>
<?php
} else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: ../login.php');
}
```

In your previous code, if user is not Manager, so they still be redirected even admin.

Comment: After Loging out and trying it with out being logged in, I allowed a non logged in user to have accesses to the page? I tried it also with a && in replace of the || still nothing.

Comment: No, `&&` will break your code because your system only have user with admin permission or manager permission, not both.

Comment: Ahh Gotcha. I figured it out also why it wasn't working, It was looking for a capital Manager in the User_Type `&& $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'Manager') {` Now Its working! Thank you!